# jQuery - div filtering via checkbox issue

Tags: jquery

I have been working on a project for filtering `div`s using `checkboxes` and so far I have it working, but I am missing one piece of the puzzle.

When you make a selection for example `Slider` it will show the only option with `Slider`.

If you then select `Full Width` it will show all options with `Slider` **and** `Full Width`

What I want is it to only show options with **both** `Slider` and `Full Width` so you **wouldn't** get a result with `Fader` and `Full Width`

Hopefully that makes sense

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var sections = $('.sectionContent');

  function updateContentVisibility() {
    var checked = $("#filterControls :checkbox:checked");
    if (checked.length) {
      sections.hide();
      checked.each(function() {
        $("." + $(this).val()).show();
      });
    } else {
      sections.show();
    }
  }

  $("#filterControls :checkbox").click(updateContentVisibility);
  updateContentVisibility();

});
```

```css
#filterControls label {
  display: block;
}
.box {
  height: 100px;
  background: #eee;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="filterControls">
  <label><b>Image Header Type</b>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Slider" name="SliderCheck" />Slider</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Fader" name="FaderCheck" />Fader</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Static" name="StaticCheck" />Static</label>
  <label><b>Image Header Styles</b>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Full-Width" name="SliderCheck" />Full Width</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Full-Screen" name="FaderCheck" />Full Screen</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Arrow-Navigation" name="CustomCheck" />Arrow Navigation</label>
</div>

<div id="siteFilter">
  <div class="sectionContent box Slider Full-Width Full-Screen Arrow-Navigation" style="display: inline-block;">
    <a href="http://www.twelve.com.au/" target="_blank">Slider / Full Width</a>
  </div>
  <div class="sectionContent box Fader Full-Width Arrow-Navigation" style="display: inline-block;">
    <a href="http://www.galpins.com.au/" target="_blank">Fader / Full Width</a>
  </div>
  <div class="sectionContent box Static Full-Width" style="display: inline-block;">
    <a href="http://www.wmcaccounting.com.au/" target="_blank">Static / Full Width</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I might be missing it, but where are you iterating over all checkboxes and hiding them once new ones have been checked?

Comment: If you check something it will find the item with the matching class, if you check two things It will find the items with matching classes, what I want is If you check two or three things I want the result to display the item with all of those classes. That better?

Comment: What do you mean if(checked.length)?

Comment: @FarzinKanzi I believe that will just indicate whether or not anything is checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to select a specific element that has two classes you need to concatenate all the classes, separating them with `.`s **without spaces** like `.class1.class2.class3`, to do that you need to update your `updateContentVisibility` logic, check this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var sections = $('.sectionContent');

  function updateContentVisibility() {
    var checked = $("#filterControls :checkbox:checked");
    if (checked.length) {
      sections.hide();
      var selectedClasses = "";
      checked.each(function() {
        selectedClasses += "." + $(this).val();

      });
      $(selectedClasses).show();
    } else {
      sections.show();
    }
  }

  $("#filterControls :checkbox").click(updateContentVisibility);
  updateContentVisibility();

});
```

```css
#filterControls label {
  display: block;
}
.box {
  height: 100px;
  background: #eee;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="filterControls">
  <label><b>Image Header Type</b>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Slider" name="SliderCheck" />Slider</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Fader" name="FaderCheck" />Fader</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Static" name="StaticCheck" />Static</label>
  <label><b>Image Header Styles</b>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Full-Width" name="SliderCheck" />Full Width</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Full-Screen" name="FaderCheck" />Full Screen</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="Arrow-Navigation" name="CustomCheck" />Arrow Navigation</label>
</div>

<div id="siteFilter">
  <div class="sectionContent box Slider Full-Width Full-Screen Arrow-Navigation" style="display: inline-block;">
    <a href="http://www.twelve.com.au/" target="_blank">Slider / Full Width</a>
  </div>
  <div class="sectionContent box Fader Full-Width Arrow-Navigation" style="display: inline-block;">
    <a href="http://www.galpins.com.au/" target="_blank">Fader / Full Width</a>
  </div>
  <div class="sectionContent box Static Full-Width" style="display: inline-block;">
    <a href="http://www.wmcaccounting.com.au/" target="_blank">Static / Full Width</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Code only answers, while providing a working solution, does not really shed a lot of insight on the changes/improvements made. Perhaps you can add a little explanation to the improved logic?

Comment: Thanks, that works perfect, sorry I had trouble explaining what I had in my head.

Comment: @Terry Thanks for your constructive comment, I updated the answer to show some explanation.

Comment: @webmonkey237, You're welecome :)